# How do you switch from a tmux pane that you've scrolled up in to another tmux pane?

Tags: tmux

If I have two tmux panes open and I go to one and scroll back to the history using `CTRL-B [`, then for some reason I can't switch to the other pane without making the current pane scroll back to the bottom. Does anyone know how to work around this? Note that I use some custom tmux configuration, as described [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/seamlessly-navigate-vim-and-tmux-splits), to make it easier to navigate between vim windows and tmux panes. Is this somehow messing up how tmux scrolling works?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're running into a conflicting default keybinding for tmux when it's in copy mode?

When tmux is running, you can check the currently active keybindings by doing `prefix+?`.  When I do this on a bare tmux config, I can see that `C-k` is bound to `send-keys -X copy-end-of-line`, and it will move a buffer that's in copy mode to the end of the buffer, like you're describing. Alternatively, if you're using `tmux`'s `copy-mode-vi`, then it looks like `C-j` is bound by default to `send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel`.

Try adding the following to your .tmux.conf:

```
unbind-key -Tcopy-mode C-k
unbind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi C-j
```

After this configuration update, I'm able to use `C-j` and `C-k`  to navigate panes like described in the article you linked.